# ValidationMessageFor with model and html attribute only - MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-validation

Working on a MVC 3 application.

I need to add a class to the validation message html. I mean for span tag.

My Model

```
 [Required(ErrorMessage = "Role Name is required")]
 [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z ]+$", 
     ErrorMessage = "Only alphabets and spaces allowed")]
 public string RoleName { get; set; }
```

Markup

```
  <label for="name">RoleName</label>
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.RoleName)
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.RoleName, "some", 
                           new { @class = "immediate" })
```

> But i could not see overloaded method like
>   **@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.RoleName, htmlAttributes)** . if i
>   give some text, it is not showing my validaton message entered in
>   model. It always shows that some text only.

Any fix for this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should be able to simply pass in `null`...

`@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.RoleName, null, new { @class = "immediate"})`

Comment: i had a null missing, tx!

Comment: Neither null nor empty string for the second argument has the effect of failing over to the error message in the model - i seem to get an auto-generated message from the framework.  Anything else prerequisite to getting this to work?